# Why couldn't Vader tell Leia was his daughter through the Force?

Tags: star-wars, a-new-hope

Obviously besides being a major plot component, why couldn't Vader when in front of Leia sense that Leia was his biological daughter?

Comment: because of plot holes :-)

Comment: Possibly because she didn't know? He found out by reading Luke's feelings, and Luke knew.

Comment: Related but *not* a duplicate: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/6935/did-darth-vader-know-leia-is-his-daughter-from-the-start

Comment: Vader simply had no idea that he had children. That's why Lucas put in that scene in the remastered Empire Strikes Back where the emperor tells Vader that Luke is Anakin's son.

Comment: @Kevin That's not how force sensitivity works..

Comment: @SachinShekhar What do you mean? If you think Jedi can feel force sensitivity alone, that's incorrect.

Comment: @Kevin Unless someone is doing force concealment, you can feel his/her force presence..

Comment: @SachinShekhar Only if they're trained in the force. When Qui-gon and Obi-wan found Anakin, they suspected his force sensitivity from his actions, and confirmed with the midichlorian test. In the post-RotJ EU, it took Luke many years to figure out how to detect force sensitivity, he couldn't just feel it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Vader was able to detect Luke only after he received training in the use of the Force.  Luke grew up a typical angsty and restless young man, zooming around on his landspeeder bullseyeing womp rats with preternatural ability, while attracting no attention from Vader or the Emperor.  Since, as far as we saw in the movies, Leia received no Force-training, she too would have gone unnoticed by Force sensitive persons.

Comment: But yet, Luke and Leia were able to feel each other with force?

Comment: @SachinShekhar: dude, they're brother and sister, ew.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Do you have any canonical source to say blood-relationship has something to do with force presence sensing?

Comment: @SachinShekhar: ah - no, I was just making a crude joke based on the *double entendre* of "feel each other with force".

Answer (score 1):

It's a continuity trap.  Orginally not only were Vader and Anakin Skywalker different men, Luke and Leia were not siblings and in fact were to become a couple.  It was in part how Han Solo became the breakout character that influenced mid-course continuity change.

Comment: If you want to post an out of universe answer that is basically "this is a plot hole", it would be better to at least make it comprehensive, showing proof that this was the plan from earlier drafts etc....

Answer (score -1):

Anakin's "force" was felt despite being a child with no training, so Luke and Leia's should also have been felt.

Comment: There's a difference between detecting a generic Force presence and detecting the Force presence of a particular person.