# Is there any detail in the canon to suggest where The Liberty and the Tantive IV met to transmit the Death Star plans?

Tags: star-wars

Pursuant to comments made by @tjd and @O.R. Mapper in my answer to [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/96825/why-didnt-it-ring-a-bell-to-vader-that-the-escape-pod-with-the-plans-landed-on), I will reproduce the note that I made:

> The points raised by @tjd and @O.R. Mapper, in the comments to this
>   answer, are solid. Why Leia was in the Tatoo system to begin with
>   depends on a question I could not find an answer to; namely, at what
>   point between Polis Massa/Darknell and Tatooine, did the Tantive IV
>   (Leia's ship) attempt to transmit the now complete Death Star plans to
>   the Liberty? The Death Star plans were not stolen all at once, but as
>   described in Operation Skyhook, in a series of actions that started in
>   AX-235 or Danuta (the canon is contradictory but seems to favor
>   Danuta), then Toprawa. The Tantive IV then moved to Polis Massa and
>   Darknell to receive the last parts of the plans, both of which are due
>   west of Tatooine in the 'south' the of galaxy.
>
> I could not find in the canon where the Liberty and Tantive IV met to
>   attempt to transfer the plans before being intercepted/interrupted by
>   the Immortal. From there the Tantive IV and a rebel detachment moved
>   to the Tatoo sector but their general location was betrayed by U-3PO
>   during the Battle of Tatooine. Their specific location in the system
>   was given away when they tried to activate an uplink station, and then
>   Vader and his contingent moved in, leading to the capture of Leia.
>
> The attempted activation of the uplink station still supports that
>   Leia was again trying to transmit the plans (from an out-of-the-way
>   location), rather than being in the Tatoo system to deliver them
>   (which she wasn't, she was there to recruit Obi-wan). She would not
>   have used the HoloNet as it was controlled by the Empire and she most
>   likely could not have transmitted the plans over any large distance
>   via hyperwave communication due its limitations, so it is reasonable
>   that she would have dropped out of hyperspace in an out-of-the-way
>   place to transmit the plans as securely as she could.

Is there any evidence in the canon to suggest where the Liberty and the Tantive IV met to attempt this transmission?

Comment: [Rogue One](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars#Rogue_One) is supposed to follow the stealing of the Death Star Plans. Perhaps we'll find out then.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up, I will update the question when that resource becomes available

Comment: On reflection I've voted to close. The answer will be forthcoming in a future property and as such, the question falls foul of our "future works" policy.

Comment: It's covered in the original radio drama, which is no longer canon.

Answer (score 3):

In short, no. There's nothing within the now-accepted [main Star Wars Canon](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/910/how-is-canonicity-of-derivative-works-determined-for-star-wars) that describes the specifics of [Operation Skyhook](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Operation_Skyhook).

Pretty much everything we know about the mission, its objectives and how it was carried out (beyond the fact that Bothans were involved) are now all considered part of the murky "Legends" canon. This even includes the name of the operation itself.

Don't despair, though. In December 2016, the upcoming stand-alone film; [Star Wars Anthology: Rogue One](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eIJuoS4cqVw) will apparently provide **brand new canon info(!!!)** about the mission and how the schematics made their way into the hands of Princess Leia.

> *"A band of resistance fighters unite for a daring mission to steal the Death Star plans..."*