# Were Luke and Leia originally planned to be related?

Tags: star-wars

When Episode 4 was filmed, did **Lucas** know Luke and Leia were brother and sister?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why do we hear Leia's Theme during Kenobi's death?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2810/why-do-we-hear-leias-theme-during-kenobis-death)

Comment: For an alternative interpretation of how Star Wars was planned/inspired, I strongly recommend the charming short film George Lucas in Love: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KkxdcCswfq0

Comment: @CamelBlues - does it make sense for someone who hasn't seen "Sheakespear in Love" to watch that film? Or all the charm will be lost? Thx

Comment: @DVX it has nothing to do with Shakespeare in Love, just the titles are similar. The charm will be lost if you know nothing about Star Wars, but I'm pretty sure those people aren't on this website.

Comment: @CamelBlues - just saw it, thanks, it's awesome! I loled for about 15 seconds at the ending.

Comment: I think that this theory could be true. Since there is a tension between the two characters this could be fals. I think that this statement is not tru no false. So thus it is anything you want it to be.

Comment: Hi, @Voldemort316, it looks like you were trying to comment on this question rather than give a solid answer. I've converted your answer into a comment for now, but don't let that put you off answering when you have a good objective answer to provide. For more information on how the site works, please have a look at the [faq]. Thanks!

Comment: @CamelBlues, dead link.

Answer (score 18):

**No**.

*To quote from my answer to [Leia's musical theme](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/2815/976):*

Even an early Leigh Brackett's 1978 draft of "*The Empire Strikes Back*" didn't have that relationship established yet - it was introduced later (Source: http://geeksofdoom.com/2010/05/15/early-draft-of-empire-strikes-back-reveals-alternate-star-wars-universe/ ).

Another related evidence for Luke and Leia not yet being related was 1978 pre-ESB book that was a sequel to "ANH" - Alan Dean Foster's "*[Splinter of the Mind's Eye](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/2815/976)*". It develops the theme of romantic interest between the two (presumably, in part, since Foster and Lucas didn't know if ANH would be a big hit and if Harrison Ford would be interested in the sequel should the sequel be based on "Splinter").

Comment: Why the downvote? This is a well-supported answer, linking to another highly upvoted and well-supported answer

Comment: @AndresF. I'm not the DVer, but at a guess, perhaps they felt that someone else's script treatment (which was rejected by Lucas) for Empire has little bearing on what Lucas did or didn't know when the original Star Wars was filmed. E.g. from the article - "Apparently, Lucas didn’t like the direction of Brackett’s script".

Comment: @NikolaiDante Fair enough! I thought it was a script they ended up not using, not one Lucas outright rejected :)

Comment: @NikolaiDante - the answer contains *two* data points :) And Foster's book WAS approved by Lucas.

Comment: Apparently Lucas said that was done on purpose to show that the two had feelings for one another, but that they did not know exactly what type of feelings. Personally, I don't buy it.

Comment: @NikolaiDante - Who you gonna trust, Lucas or your own lying eyes? :)

Comment: "Lying eyes" ?!?

Comment: @NikolaiDante - It's a [Groucho Marx](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Groucho_Marx) mis-[quote](http://quotations.about.com/od/funnymovieandtvquotes/a/grouchomarx1.htm)

Answer (score 9):

According to Lucas, yes.

However, [wookieepedia](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Splinter_of_the_Mind%27s_Eye) has this to say on the relationship in Splinter of the Minds Eye (the first Star Wars EU book):

> At the time it was written, the familial relationship between Luke,
>   Leia, and Darth Vader had yet to be revealed. Therefore, some
>   inconsistencies are evident and unavoidable. Most noticeably the
>   sexual tension depicted between Luke and Leia in this book, which in
>   retrospect would be considered inappropriate in most countries.
>   (Although Lucas claimed to have had the Star Wars saga mapped out even
>   at this early stage, the fact that he allowed this plot element to
>   remain in Foster's novel has been cited as evidence that he hadn't yet
>   decided on the characters' true backstory.) However, Lucas has stated
>   before, that this tension was on purpose, to show that the two had
>   feelings for one another, but that they did not know exactly what type
>   of feelings.

Some background on Splinter:

> Splinter of the Mind's Eye was the first-ever Expanded Universe novel
>   to be written and published. According to an interview with its
>   author, Alan Dean Foster, in Empire magazine, the novel had been
>   written to be filmed as a low budget sequel as a fallback plan in case
>   Star Wars hadn't been a huge success. This accounts for why the book
>   takes place almost entirely on a fog-shrouded planet. Additionally,
>   Harrison Ford was not signed for the sequel as of the writing of the
>   book, which is why Han Solo does not appear in it. Although George
>   Lucas is credited as the author of Star Wars: From the Adventures of
>   Luke Skywalker, the novelization of Star Wars Episode IV: A New Hope,
>   was in fact written by Alan Dean Foster. Foster's early involvement in
>   the Star Wars universe gave him the opportunity to write this book.
>   Though Foster was granted a great amount of leniency in developing the
>   story, one requirement was that a lot of props from Star Wars Episode
>   IV: A New Hope could be reused when filming the new film. According to
>   Foster, Lucas' only request upon inspecting the manuscript was the
>   removal of a dogfight in space undertaken by Luke and Leia before they
>   crash-land on Mimban. Presumably, this sequence would have cost too
>   much money to create.

Comment: I realize this is a paranoid question, but can Lucas be trusted on this? :)

Comment: @AndresF. - no.

Comment: @AndresF. Pretty much, no. His version of events varies a lot, which is why I went with "according to..." rather than a flat out yes. Personally, I doubt much of what came later was properly mapped out when Star Wars was made, but that's just IMO.

Comment: Lucas is not to be trusted on *anything* relating to what was originally planned or not.

Comment: Lucas also planned to have Disney take over the franchise.

Answer (score 1):

No. Han Solo in an old script may not have survived. And even if he did, there was a chance he knew Leia and Luke were truly in love. There was a bigger triangle between them. The "twins bit" was just quickly thrown in for Return of the Jedi.

Answer (score 1):

I don't agree [with the other answers.] It is established in Empire Strikes Back that they are brother and sister. Near the end, when Luke is hanging onto the city's [underside antenna], he begs for Ben and gets no answer. Then he says "Leia, hear me, Leia," and she hears him through the power of the force, establishing her as the other one.

Comment: Punctuation would go a long way here. I also have no idea what "TV Ariel" is.

Comment: And how does that necessarily imply that they were brother and sister? It fits with what we learned in RotJ, but it's not hard to imagine a different explanation (they're joined because they're fated for each other, for example).

Comment: The question asks about the first (i.e. number 4) SW, not *The Empire Strikes Back*